# Error The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2016, sqldatasource

I have a 2016 access file, when I try to access this file with an SQL or Access datasource in visual studio I get the following error message:

> Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection. Please make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is online. 
>   The database you are trying to open requires a newer version of Microsoft Access

I checked my database and I don't have any Large Number in it so I'm not sure what exactly is the problem.
It was working fine before I did some changes with a few Date/Time data type but I since changed all the Date/Time to Short Text. I'm not certain if it has any relation to the error message but it was the only change I've made before the error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and its stems from the use of new data fields.

Eliminating them alone did not do the trick. When you use one of the new field types it steps the version up to 16.7, which is not compatible with earlier access versions.

Note that you can get the version number with `? Currentdb.Version` in the immediate window

I had to run the compact and repair routine in order to get the version to step down.